# how do i call DAO method using webservice

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I am new for java restful webservice, i write needed methods in my dao already, now i want to call those method using webservice. i tried below mentioned code

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
   <!--  <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.demo.service</param-value>
    </init-param> -->
     <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.demo.service.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

RestfullWebService.Java

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import com.test.dao.RestDao;


@Path("/endPoint/service")
public class EndPointService {

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("dao")
 RestDao dao;

public RestDao getDao() {
    return dao;
}

public void setDao(RestDao dao) {
    this.dao= dao;
}

@GET
public void name() {
    System.out.println("Inside Get Method");
}

@POST
@Path("/author")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String author(String s) {
    System.out.println("I am Author.. This is My Testing Purpose");
    String res=s;
    try{
    String daoRes=dao.getempemailsearch(res); // Got Error NullPointer Exception
    return daoRes;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Exception";
    }

    }

   }
```

RestDao.Java

```
public interface RestDao 
{
public String getempemailsearch(String name);
}
```

ResDaoImpl.Java

```
@Repository
@Singleton
public class RestDaoImpl implements RestDao
{

 @Transactional(value="transactionManager")
 public String getempemailsearch(String name)
 {
   System.out.println("Hi This is MY DAO");
 }
}
```

RestClient.Java

```
 package com.restfull.robert;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
 import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
 import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
 import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;


 public class RestClient {
  private final static String URI="http://localhost:8080/resttest/rest/endPoint/service/author";
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Client client=Client.create();
    WebResource webresource= client.resource(URI);
  /*        ClientResponse   clientresponse=webresource.get(ClientResponse.class);//get 
 */     
    ClientResponse clientresponse=webresource.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).entity("arjun").post(ClientResponse.class);
    if(clientresponse.getStatus() == 200){
        String op=clientresponse.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("Client Side OutPut "+op);
    }
 }

 }
```

In this line i got NULL Pointer Exception, I need solution for this.

```
String daoRes=dao.getempemailsearch(res); // Got Error NullPointer Exception
```

Now i got outPut:

> I am Author.. This is My Testing Purpose
>   Null Pointer Exception
>   Client Side OutPut Exception

Expected OutPut:

> I am Author.. This is My Testing Purpose
>   Client Side OutPut Hi This is MY DAO